# Jasmine: How to spy imported function/constructor on ES6?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6, spy, es6-module-loader

I am wondering how can I spy/stub function on Jasmine if I am using ES6 imports/exports with babel?

```
import MobileDetect from 'mobile-detect';
it('should spy MobileDetect', () => {
    MobileDetect = jasmine.createSpy('MobileDetect');
});`
```

The first problem is that I can't rewrite read-only module

Module build failed: `SyntaxError: /Users/oleg/projects/rp/popup/lib/spec/popup.spec.js: "MobileDetect" is read-only`

```
it('should spy MobileDetect', () => {
    console.log(MobileDetect.prototype.constructor === MobileDetect); //true
    spyOn( MobileDetect.prototype, 'constructor' );
    console.log(MobileDetect.prototype.constructor === MobileDetect); //false
});`
```

I tried this approach, but it doesn't work too... MobileDetect.prototype.constructor spied, but MobileDetect directly not.

What do you think about this problem?

Comment: You can't spy on `MobileDetect` because the variable's value can't be rewritten to a new spying function. My guess: what if you did `var myMobileDetect = MobileDetect` and then spied on `myMobileDetect` instead? Obviously, you'd need to change your code to use `myMobileDetect`, though.

Comment: I'm wondering what you are trying to accomplish in your test. Are you looking to create a spy that mimics `MobileDetect`'s methods? (ie a mock)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) for mocking `require()` statements in your tests, you can use [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) to do the same with ES6 imports.

Your test setup might look something like this;

```
import myModuleUnderTest from '../src/popup';

beforeEach(() => {
    this.fakeMobileDetect = jasmine.createSpy();
    myModuleUnderTest.__Rewire__('MobileDetect', this.fakeMobileDetect);
});
```

Which you can revert to normal with;

```
afterEach(() => {
    myModuleUnderTest.__ResetDependency__('MobileDetect');
});
```